# Determine if $x$ is in $H$ and if it is find $[x]_B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

$$
v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
3  \\ 
1  \\ 
2  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ 
0  \\ 
1  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
x = \begin{bmatrix}
9  \\ 
2  \\ 
7  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$B = \{v_1, v_2\}$ is a basis for $H = \mathrm{Span}\{v_1, v:2\}$.

Determine if $x$ is in $H$, and if it is, find the coordinate vector $[x]_B$ of $x$ relative to $B$.

So what I started to do was make the Matrix $[v_1 v_2 x]$:
$$
[v_1 v_2 x]=
\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&9\\ 
1&0&2\\ 
2&1&7
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and then computed the RREF
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&2\\ 
0&1&3\\ 
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is where I get stuck, because there is zero row on the bottom so there is a free variable. Does this mean that $x$ is NOT in $H$?

Answer (score 1):

Your result means that $$x= 2v_1+3v_2$$

I think you've lost track of what your computations mean.  When you set up the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
3&1&9\\ 
1&0&2\\ 
2&1&7
\end{bmatrix}$$

that is shorthand for the system of equations $$
\begin{align}
3a+1b&=9\\
1a+0b&=2\\
2a+1b&=7
\end{align}$$
that is to say $$av_1+bv_2 = x$$

When you reduced the matrix to RREF you were effectively solving for $a$ and $b$.

**EDIT**
As for the last couple of sentences in your question, the row of zeros just means that $$0a+0b=0,$$ which is true, though not very interesting.  If you had gotten a row like $$0\ \ 0\ \ 1$$
at the bottom, that would mean $$0a+0b=1$$
and since that's nonsense, it would mean that $x$ is not in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$2v_1+3v_2 = x $$ therefore the answer is yes.

$x$ is in the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$